# MySQL query caching: limited to a maximum cache size of 128 MB?

Tags: caching, mysql, performance, innodb

My application is very database intensive so I've tried really hard to make sure the application and the MySQL database are working as efficiently as possible together.

Currently I'm tuning the MySQL query cache to get it in line with the characteristics of queries being run on the server.

`query_cache_size` is the maximum amount of data that may be stored in the cache and `query_cache_limit` is the maximum size of a single resultset in the cache.

My current MySQL query cache is configured as follows:

```
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_limit=1M
```

`tuning-primer.sh` gives me the following tuning hints about the running system:

```
QUERY CACHE
Query cache is enabled
Current query_cache_size = 128 M
Current query_cache_used = 127 M
Current query_cache_limit = 1 M
Current Query cache Memory fill ratio = 99.95 %
Current query_cache_min_res_unit = 4 K
However, 21278 queries have been removed from the query cache due to lack of memory
Perhaps you should raise query_cache_size
MySQL won't cache query results that are larger than query_cache_limit in size
```

And `mysqltuner.pl` gives the following tuning hints:

```
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 31.3% (39K cached / 125K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 2300654

Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 128M)
```

Both tuning scripts suggest that I should raise the `query_cache_size`. However, increasing the `query_cache size` over 128M may reduce performance according to `mysqltuner.pl` (see http://mysqltuner.pl/).

How would you tackle this problem? Would you increase the query_cache_size despite `mysqltuner.pl`'s warning or try to adjust the querying logic in some way? Most of the data access is handled by Hibernate, but quite a lot of hand-coded SQL is used in the application as well.

Comment: `query_cache_size` should be around 100 to 200 MB. use as a small `query_cache_limit` if you can, thus storing as many small query results as possible in the ram (== dont use the 1MB default value when using query cache).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually "too big cache size" warnings are issued under assumption that you have few physical memory and the cache itself well need to be swapped or will take resources that are required by the `OS` (like file cache).

If you have enough memory, it's safe to increase `query_cache size` (I've seen installations with `1GB` query cache).

But are you sure you are using the query cache right? Do have lots of *verbatim repeating* queries? Could you please post the example of a typical query?

Comment: The "Query cache efficiency" is around 30 %, so I would assume that roughly that percentage of queries are "verbatim repeating queries". Or am I missing something? :-)

Comment: If you repeat `1` query `30,000` times or repeat `30,000` queries `1` time each, this will give you the same number of cache hits but different required cache size.

Comment: There are a lot of mentions (by the manual itself even) that you do not want it to get too high. I've come across this old-ish answer, so a fair warning. I'll add my own answer as well if I get around to it

Comment: Well, I added my own answer, because I think this is incorrect. I don't think you want to do 1gb cache size if "a couple of hunderd" is probably too big according to the manual :) ... I added my comment as a warning that this might not be correct (anymore?)

Comment: @Nanne: so you tried a 1GB cache and experienced troubles with it?

Comment: No, don't put words in my mouth please. As I said in my answer, there CAN be averse effects when increasing the cache, it all depends on the queries you do. The advice by oracle itself is to not just make it bigger. This has nothing to do with available system-mem per se, but more with the way this query-cache works. But why not check my answer and the sources I quote. That's what it is for.

Comment: @Nanne: no problem, I just wanted to clarify whether you have actually experienced troubles or just citing manuals. As I told, I have seen (nicely working) installations with 1GB cache which was there for a reason.

Comment: the answer give below this is actually the correct one.

Answer (score 20):

The warning issued by mysqltuner.py is actually relevant even if your cache has no risk of being swapped.
It is well-explained in the following:
http://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/mysql_query_cache_sizing

Basically MySQL spends more time grooming the cache the bigger the cache is and since the cache is very volatile under even moderate write loads (queries gets cleared often), putting it too large will have an adverse effect on your application performance. Tweak the `query_cache_size` and `query_cache_limit` for your application, try finding a breaking point where you have most hits per insert, a low number of `lowmem_prunes` and keep a close eye on your database servers load while doing so too.

Answer (score 14):

You *should* be easy on increasing your cache, it is not only a "not that much available mem" thing!

Reading for instance [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) you get this quote:

> Be cautious about sizing the query cache excessively large, which increases the overhead required to maintain the cache, possibly beyond the benefit of enabling it. Sizes in tens of megabytes are usually beneficial. Sizes in the hundreds of megabytes might not be.

There are [various](http://www.dbasquare.com/kb/how-query-cache-can-cause-performance-problems/) other [sources](https://blogs.oracle.com/dlutz/entry/mysql_query_cache_sizing) you can check out!

> A non-zero prune rate may be an indication that you should increase the size of your query cache. However, keep in mind that the overhead of maintaining the cache is likely to increase with its size, so do this in small increments and monitor the result. If you need to dramatically increase the size of the cache to eliminate prunes, there is a good chance that your workload is not a good match for the query cache.

So don't just put as much as you can in that query cache!

The best thing, would be to gradually increase the query cache and measure performance on your site. It's some sort of default in performance questions, but in cases like this 'testing' is one of the best things you can do.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful with setting the **query_cache_size** and limit too high. MySQL only uses a single thread to read from the query cache.

With the **query_cache_size** set to 4G and **query_cache_limit** 12M we had a query cache rate of 85% but noticed a recurring spikes in connections.

After changing the **query_cache_size** to 256M with 64K **query_cache_limit** the query cache ratio dropped to 50% but the overall performance increased.

Answer (score 4):

Overhead for Query cache is around 10% so I would disable query caching. Usually if you can't get your hit rate over 40 or 50 % maybe query cache isn't right for your database.

I've blog about this topic... [Mysql query_cache_size performance here](http://haydenjames.io/mysql-query-cache-size-performance/).

Answer (score 3):

Query Cache gets invalidated/flush every time there is an insert, Use InnoDB/cache and avoid query cache or set it to a very small value.

Comment: Which setting are you referring to when you say "InnoDB/cache"?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size=90% of memory available or as high as you can

Comment: this may be a valid suggestion, but without an explanation on why Innodb cache is any better / different, I can't upvote

Comment: From my understanding, the innodb buffer pool cache is a general purpose cache (tables, etc.) while the query cache is specific to, as you might have guessed, queries. So, they don't conflict nor is one better than the other. Both are required to tune as they have different purpose/goal/functionality/value.